# Haskell - Parse error in pattern: (función)

Tags: haskell

Me he encontrado con un problema que a priori no le veo ningún sentido. Es una simple función implementando guardas, idéntica a como la implementó mi profesor, a él le funciona y a mí no. Ninguno de los dos encontramos por qué puede ser. Cualquier ayuda la agradecería un montón. Gracias de antemano...

Este es el código, es una simple ordenación de una tupla con dos elementos:

```
module EDPractica1 where

import        Test.QuickCheck

orden :: Ord a => (a,a) -> (a,a)
orden (x,y)
      x <= y = (x,y)
      otherwise = (y,x)
```

Y el error es el siguiente:>

```
Prelude> :r
[1 of 1] Compiling EDPractica1      ( EDPractica1.hs, interpreted )

EDPractica1.hs:4:1: error: Parse error in pattern: ordena2
  |
4 | ordena2 (x,y) 
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: El error que pones poco tiene qué ver con el código. No sabemos cómo ejecutas el código, ni si has instalado _QuickCheck_, ni qué tiene qué ver VSCode para que no pongas tú las guardas que faltan en la definición. Como no usas QuickCheck directamente, ¿has probado a comentar el import a ver qué pasa?

Answer (score 0):

No olviden poner '|' para indicar guardas. VSCode puede jugárosla poniendolo y en realidad solo muestra la tabulación, deben de poner el símbolo, si no da error.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Las guardas deben llevar el signo de `|` (pipe)

La estructura de la guarda en Haskell es la siguiente

```
nombredelafuncion :: entradas y salidas
nombredelafuncion argumentos de entrada
   | argumnentos
   | otherwise = argumentos por defecto
```

Teniendo en cuenta esta estructura dada, la función de la pregunta corregida queda de la siguiente forma.

```
orden :: Ord a => (a,a) -> (a,a)
orden (x,y)
   | x <= y = (x,y)
   | otherwise = (y,x)
```